# Trying to obtain azure webapp status using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm encountering an issue when running the get-AzWebApp command in powershell.  All I'm trying to do is get a list of the web apps in a particular resource group, then check that they're in a running state.

The command

```
 $Apps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<my group name>"
```

There are only 8 web apps in this RG, but every time I run it, it takes a good minute or so to run, but then fails with the following error ..

The script failed due to call depth overflow.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [AppServiceStatusCheck_Test.ps1], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be great.

Comment: The version of powershell is 5.1.19041.1682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that using the below snippet but you will need `az cli` installed.

```
 az webapp list --resource-group YOURRESOURCEGROUP --query "[?state=='Running']"
```

Az webapp documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-list

Az installation instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-8.0.0

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'm fine using the az cli command line via the portal, but I've tended to use powershell when writing scripts that get called from our on-prem scheduler application.  I'll certainly install the module to try this going forward though.

Answer (score 0):

If you google the error `The script failed due to call depth overflow` you get some examples which suggest that either the syntax or the logic within your script is not quite correct or causing an infinite loop of some descritpion.

The error is surfaced from `AppServiceStatusCheck_Test.ps1`. Do you have more context in that script that you can provide?

As an alternative to GeralexGR suggestion using PowerShell commands and `Search-AzGraph`.

```
# Build a Kusto query as a string
$query = "resources
| where type == 'microsoft.web/sites'
| extend state = properties.state
| project name,state,resourceGroup,location,id,type,kind,subscriptionId
"

# Search-AzGraph requires the Az.ResourceGraph module which is not part of the Az module.
# Install-Module -Name Az.ResourceGraph -Scope CurrentUser
Search-AzGraph -Query $query
```

If I am just querying Azure I tend to use a Kusto query with `Search-AzGraph` for speed of complex queries if your dataset is quite large. You can also cheat and find the resources in the portal then click the 'Open Query' to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help in getting me to look at the rest of my script!  Although I was able to run the get-azwebapp command in isolation, it was failing in my script because I was trying to build it into a function.  The function began with "Function Get-AzWebApp" which is the command name so I should have named it something else.  Changing it to "Function Get-mywebapps" (for example) then worked fine.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Yeah, One of the posts I seen with a quick search of the error was naming conflict between script and function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230401/error-calldepthoverflow-when-running-powershell-st.html